# How can I load the higher resolution image asynchronously to not count agains LCP?

Tags: javascript, image, largest-contentful-paint

[This](https://www.corewebvitals.io/pagespeed/fix-slow-hero-images-core-web-vitals) post tells us a technique to reduce LCP.

- First load a low-resolution image
- Then load a high-resolution image asynchronously (to not interfere with the LCP)
- When loaded, show the high-resoslution image

And [this](https://medium.com/chili-tech-blog/lazy-loading-image-1-7667550de839) shows that in React code, but it does not load the image asynchronously. When I used this code, I see that the browser loads both images, and my LCP does not change at all.

How can I load the high-resolution image async? And would it truly reduce LCP if it gets loaded async?